# Access REST API with Connected-App and JWT Bearer Token Flow

Tags: oauth2, sandbox, php, jwt

I read this article and created php demo script.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Environment: Sandbox

OAuth Scopes: api, refresh_token, offline_access

OAuth cert: ../../certs/test.crt

OAuth Trusted IP: My GLOBAL IP

Profiles: System Administrator

Environment Variables:

```
SF_IS_SAND_BOX=true
SF_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY=(CONSUMER KEY in Connected App page)
SF_OAUTH_USER=(ADMINISTRATOR USER EMAIL being used in sandbox login page)
```

```php
<?php

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class SalesForceApiService {
    protected $jwtEndpoint;

    protected $jwtIssuer;

    protected $jwtAudienve;

    protected $jwtUser;

    protected $jwtCert;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->jwtEndpoint = env('SF_IS_SAND_BOX', true)
            ? 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
            : 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
        $this->jwtIssuer = env('SF_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY');
        $this->jwtAudience = env('SF_IS_SAND_BOX', true)
            ? 'https://test.salesforce.com'
            : 'https://login.salesforce.com';
        $this->jwtUser = env('SF_OAUTH_USER');
        $this->jwtCert = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../certs/test.pem');
    }

    public function connect() {
        $payload = $this->getJwtPayload();
        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $this->jwtCert, 'RS256');
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ])->post($this->jwtEndpoint, [
            'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion' => $jwt,
        ]);

        return $response;
    }

    protected function getJwtPayload() {
        return [
            'iss' => $this->jwtIssuer,
            'aud' => $this->jwtAudience,
            'sub' => $this->jwtUser,
            'exp' => time() + 3 * 60,
        ];
    }
}
```

However the following error was reported.

`{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}`

### [ADD]

The way to create the signature.

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 > test.pem
$ openssl req -new -key test.pem -out test.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in test.csr -signkey test.pem -out test.crt
```

I uploaded test.crt to my SalesForce Connected-App.

Comment: Either you're building the request incorrectly (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#sending-form-url-encoded-requests) or you're not signing it with the right key or your connected app is not set up with the right key. The last possibility is that it's a timing issue - wait 24 hours and try again, some people have reported this as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Correcting wrong request using `Http::asForm`, The error: `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"}` was returned. I created the signature by the way I added to question. 24 hours have passed. I'm setting up keys and trying again.

Comment: I disabled `Web サーバフローの秘密が必要` and `更新トークンフローの秘密が必要` option in Japanese, then finally I got access token.

Comment: `Secret required` options are for a different flow, they don't apply to JWT Bearer..so selecting or unselecting them shouldn't have made a difference. Happy to hear you got it to work!

Comment: In that case, filling cert properties (Address, Company, etc...) is the different. Thanks.